# Macbook Pro locks up after lid closed for a while

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, performance

I was given an A1398 (Macbook Pro 15" Retina Mid-2015) and am experiencing frequent freezes after the lid is closed for a while, assuming the computer is in sleep mode.

The freeze after opening time is inconsistent. Sometimes it is immediately after I log in, sometimes a few minutes after use, and sometimes several. It always begins in the middle of use. One application freezes. I try to quit it, which does not work. Soon, all applications freeze showing the spinning cursor and it is impossible to even access the top menu bar. However, the cursor still moves, but keyboard shortcuts are not registered (probably because Finder locks up too). Ultimately, a manual power cycle is required.

When I received the laptop, it was not holding a charge and therefore would not turn on. I replaced the MagSafe myself. It was purchased from iFixit (https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Retina-Late-2013-Mid-2015-MagSafe-2-DC-In-Board/IF117-024?o=1). The only other damage is the right-side Thunderbolt 2 port does not work. No display is detected by the computer, nor is an input detected on any monitor I have tried. There is no way of knowing if I caused this damage during the MagSafe replacement or if it was prior.

Probably unrelated, but I also sometimes have difficulty transferring a call from my iPhone to my MacBook. Sometimes, when the call starts on my iPhone and I try to move audio to my MacBook, the call screen will slide in quickly and slide out, and the call drops. This is independent of whether the phone is ringing or has been answered. A reboot of either device does not fix the problem. Once it happens once, it continues and only time magically fixes it. I do not believe this is related to the freezes because I experience this with both my personal and work MacBooks, which are both the same exact model.

The only external peripheral connected is a Magic Mouse 2.

The first thing I did after the repair was I reinstalled the OS and upgraded to Big Sur. The problem occurred before installing most applications, so I do not believe it is caused by an installed application. At the time I first experienced the problem, the only possible non-native background processes and daemons installed were from ExpressVPN, Dropbox, and Spark. I am never connected to the VPN when closing the lid.

I will often begin using the laptop in the evening. When done, I will leave the laptop on, with the lid closed and charging, on a marble countertop. I usually do not use it until the following evening. I always unplug the charger before use.

I plan on making my use more frequent, so this now poses a problem.

Comment: From the physical problems - MagSafe charging/TBolt port not working, etc, my first guess with the unit lying on my virtual test bench is that it has hardware problems. Disable any and all Bluetooth devices and Bluetooth on mobile devices. Connect a USB keyboard and mouse. Another thing to consider, until the problem has been fixed, is to shut down the computer when you are done, and you will not be using it for several hours, or overnight. I think your MBP needs looking at by a tech. It could be any number of things undiagnosable over IP packets.

Comment: @IconDaemon "It could be any number of things undiagnosable over IP packets." I love how you worded that.

I have slowly transitioned to programming on macOS. I have considered the possibility it is the MagSafe and charging. I plan on leaving it overnight without the charger a few times. If it doesn't lock it, maybe there is a power issue. I am also going to try a full system wipe and reinstall. If nothing else works, I will put the PCB under the microscope.